# Showing base64 data with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64

I'm facing a problem when showing `base64` data please see below:

When I'm using for debugging:

```
<%= debug @photo %>
```

Showing like below image:

[image]

And this is correct.

When I'm using for the show:

```
<%= @photo %>
```

Showing like below image:

[image]

And this is not correct!

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your data isn't Base64 *except* when you call debug which uses YAML which uses Base64.

Comment: for debugging you might want to write to a file on the file system and verify that it can be decoded: `bundle exec rails console` : `photo = Photo.find(xxxx)` : `File.open('./tmp/photo1.xxxx, 'wb') { |f| f.write(Base64.decode64(photo)) }` then open that file from the rails tmp directory, if it is valid then use this technique to render it in an html page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716/317989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Base64 encoded data, you should try below code:

```
 require "base64"

 <%= Base64.encode64(@photo) %>
```

Learn [more](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#module-Base64-label-Example)